# Getting past a whole lot of anti-debug measures for a windows exe

Tags: debuggers, anti-debugging, disassemblers

I'm trying to debug a windows exe that is really full of anti-debug measures. It has pretty much everything you can think of DBGuiremotebreakin, Ntsetinformationthread, NtQueryInformationProcess, the works. The only problem is that I really need to get into it. The anti-debug stuff is mixed in all throughout the code with important computations that are used for the stuff I want to see. How could I start trying to spoof the measures so I can observe register usage unfoiled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use something like Scylla Hide

https://github.com/nihilus/ScyllaHide

It has plugins for most popular debuggers. It has lots of hiding options and presets for advanced packers like Themida.

You can also try Titan Hide.

https://github.com/mrexodia/TitanHide

Comment: My +1 vote  for this one. I am not Olly fan, but this one obviously did the work for topicstarter. Well done :)

Comment: sorry, took a little break to recoup after that effort. This is flagged as best answer. Thank you!

Comment: The second link seems broken in the way that the repository was deleted

Comment: Updated link to new repo

Answer (score 1):

I think, in such cases strategy is very depend on type of anti-debug mechanisms used, sort of computations that you are looking for, and amount of time you ready to spent on this task.

IMO you should follow this plan:

1. statically analyse the binary [IDA] to map all those anti-debug features and points of interest you looking for.
2. if possible, try to understand those important computations without actual file execution. you can re-create them in python, run them as separate binary or emulate them with, for example, pyEmu https://github.com/codypierce/pyemu
3. if [2] was not successful, carefully make yourself thru each anti-debug feature during execution of binary under debugger. Use map you built in [1] to make it faster

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Maybe Sylla hide or Titan hide may be of assistance here as well. Plugins for most debuggers are available.

Comment: thanks this does help. I will try to start with that. Basically a string is created through modifications to the .data of the exe. I want to know the string that it generates. It might be possible to selectively nop all the anti-debug features, but there's a lot and they're prolific, and usually around critical code.

Comment: I wish I could upvote you 1000 times @GhassanIdriss but I can't even once, because it was just a comment. Those two in conjunction worked where others didn't! I was able to get the string generated fine using ODBG.

Comment: I made an answer for it